# How to Fetch text from array.xml in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am trying to fetch text from array.xml which i have added in strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <string name="app_name">RawFetc</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string-array name="array" >
        <item>Hello I am List</item>
        <item> I am als a List</item>

    </string-array>    
</resources>
```

And the java class for this is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);

    }
}
```

I want to know the next step after this, to show the text when application get starts. Please help

Comment: You need to elaborate on this - is there an issue with the value arr is being set to? Or are you trying to find out how to actually display these values in the UI? You will need to provide more information about how your UI is implemented and how you hope to display the strings.

Comment: Yes i just want to implement this in my UI, when app will load the content of array.xml should display that's it.. please

Comment: It's the "Implement this in my UI" that you need to elaborate on. Will it be in a list? Will it be in a text view? You haven't shown us at all what R.layout.activity_main looks like or where you intend that information to be displayed.

Comment: I want this to show in my UI with a TextView defined in main.xml, canu only let me know how to display this aaray in screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now since you have fetched array using

```
String[] arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
```

You can fetch string from `arr` using indices like
`arr[0], arr[1], ...` so on.

Declare a `TextView` in `activity_main.xml` which will show the text from the array.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt); //The id could be different 
    String[] arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
    txtView.setText(arr[0]); //arr[1], arr[2] , whatever you want to set

}
```

Comment: Can you plz help with code, i just want to fetch the array elements and display in main_activity.xml.. If you will help with code that will be more helpful as i am complete noob Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is the accepted answer, please mark it as such (Click the check mark next to the voting). It would be helpful if you included your main.xml file for others with the same question.